# How to add optional parameters to the mapdist function?

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm trying to enter optional parameters using the R ggmap package to get travel times considering traffic, however, I haven't been able to figure out how to do it.

For instance, the following code results in 1844 seconds

```
library(ggmap)
tripinfo <- mapdist('Chandler', 'Phoenix', 
                    mode = 'driving')
tripinfo$seconds
```

This is identical to plugging in the following API URL directly into a web browser (note that this will not run directly since I've substituted my real API key with "apikey")

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Chandler&destinations=Phoenix&mode=driving&language=en-EN&key=apikey
```

However, if I try to add the optional parameters that should give me the travel time including traffic with the ggmap mapdist function, I still get the same 1844 seconds:

```
tripinfo <- mapdist('Chandler', 'Phoenix', 
                    mode = 'driving', traffic_model='best_guess', departure_time='now')
```

Conversely, if I enter the additional parameters directly into the URL, I get a "duration_in_traffic" "value" of 1700 seconds (this is the info I want).  Here's that URL:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Chandler&destinations=Phoenix&mode=driving&language=en-EN&key=apikey&traffic_mode=best_guess&departure_time=now
```

Any ideas how to add the optional parameters to the ggmap mapdist function (or perhaps there is another way to do it entirely, but still using R)?

Comment: The `googleway` package could be helpful.

Comment: That worked well.   Thank you